# $firebase undefined in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

For some reason, $firebase is undefined when I try to use it. I'm pretty new to Angular, so I'm guessing there is just some disconnect in the way I split up my files. I can get all of the code to work properly if it's in just one HTML page, but I want to split it all up, as my app will have different pages.

controllers.js

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['firebase']).
  controller('StoryController', [function($scope, $firebase) {
    var storiesRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    $scope.stories = $firebase(storiesRef);
    $scope.addStory = function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
      $scope.stories.$add({title: $scope.title, text: $scope.text});
      $scope.text = "";
    }
  }]);
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.filters',
  'myApp.services',
  'myApp.directives',
  'myApp.controllers'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/stories', {templateUrl: 'partials/stories.html'});
  $routeProvider.when('/addStory', {templateUrl: 'partials/addStory.html', controller: 'StoryController'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

EDIT: Forgot to include the error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at new <anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/app/js/controllers.js:8:22)
    at d (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:30:452)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:31:80)
    at http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:62:23
    at link (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular-route/angular-route.min.js:7:208)
    at F (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:49:345)
    at f (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:42:399)
    at http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:42:67
    at http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:43:299
    at z (http://localhost:8000/app/lib/angular/angular.min.js:47:23) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

And I have included all the scripts I have at the end of my main template.

Comment: Is there any error output? Do you have included the necessary scripts?

Comment: Just added the error output, and yes, all the required scripts are included. Everything works just fine when it's all in one giant file. I'm just having trouble splitting it all up to make it manageable.

Comment: Is the js file minified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using inline dependencies but not defining them correctly;

```
controller('StoryController', ['$scope', '$firebase', function($scope, $firebase) {
```

Read more about dependency injection here; http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: I knew it was something simple! Thank you!